# Swift Syntax related. how do i write this better?

Tags: swift, data-structures, syntax, casting

I have a line of code as below. I feel like there needs to be a more succinct way of writing my code below. Any criticism, suggestions are welcomed.

```
        filteredArray = ((SomeSingletonClass.sharedControl().groups as NSDictionary).allValues as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(<#predicate: NSPredicate#>)
```

Comment: Why do you need the casts to NSDictionary and NSArray?

Comment: after getting "allValues", in order to run filteredArrayUsingPredicate(), I need to cast it as NSArray. that function is only avail in NSArray class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Swift rather than trying to force everything back into Cocoa:

```
let filteredArray = filter(SomeSingletonClass.sharedControl().groups.values) {
    predicate.evaluateWithObject($0)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was wondering what the $0 is? I haven't come across that in my Swift journey yet. Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: `$0` is the first parameter passed to a closure. `f($0)` is shorthand for `x in f(x)`. See "Shorthand Argument Names" in The Swift Programming Language https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94